# Typescript if statement does not understand referenced check

Tags: typescript

If we have a typed object with possibly undefined values:

```js
type Person = {
  name: string | undefined;
  nickName: string | undefined;
};

const personObj: Person = {
  name: 'Random Name',
  nickName: 'Random NickName',
};
```

In typescript this conditional allows us to split string and there's no compile error

```js
if (personObj.nickName) {
  const splitValue = personObj.nickName.split(' ');
  console.log(splitValue);
}
```

However, if I check store the `personObj.nickName` in a variable, the string split throws an error:

```js
const nickNameExists = personObj.nickName;
// or const nickNameExists = Boolean(personObj.nickName);

if (nickNameExists) {
  const splitValue = personObj.nickName.split(' '); // error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
  console.log(splitValue);
}
```

Why does Typescript not work with conditions that hold a reference?
[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwFBSlQEMBbCALikWHgEtUBzKAHygFdUATCAM3ok4BufIVoBjANYA5UhSo16TVh259UA4QF9huMWmpRISNAHkARgCtKcY+ix4CxMpQDkAJSJdkJKDLIuAGhFUcWlZVw8vHylQvwhA3G1cXX1gUUk4gFEAD1pqRExDBBRUcwsAOhCM2R1aHigACiqwshy84EQAShwRPVQDRDAAG1pgADUiIbZoLCMSssrY2XLBkeAGlygXTuECPpQhiHKh5AYG1dGJqYgdxNwgA)

Comment: you should just use the ?. syntax (if will call split only if personObj.nickName exists). As it will already exists, as typescript is "dumb", it will allways evalute to 'nickName.split(" ")' but typescript will be happy as it will be sure that split method exists

Comment: Yes, but why is it still needed? I already checked it in the if statement

Comment: type checking is done by typescript no matter the code before. Your condition ensures *you* that it's not undefined but as far as it goes for the typescript transpiler, it could still be "undefined" as it is a possible *type*. The main issue is that the transpiler is dumb AND really intelligent, so it would fail on those obvious things for us. But if it was "smarter", transpiling time would take a lot more time.

Answer (score 0):

use interface instead of type

```
interface Person = {
  name: string | undefined;
  nickName: string | undefined;
};

const personObj: Person = {
  name: 'Random Name',
  nickName: 'Random NickName',
};
```

Comment: nope,  [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQAVYGcD2ZUDewqqYCAtlAPwBcqWEM4A5qgD6oCuYAJlHOCg8A3MVIgkAawByFanQZMwrDtz4CwQ0QF9RwJHgaoADtjwB5AEYArOphi58AXkJiylOgHIASgl45yVFlKTwAaNwkZOS9ff0DpSOCoMOBdYH1DCHEpJIBRAA8QBixUF1MHCxsAOjBEuT0QOFQAClqcuQKiiCwASlcSAzAjLGMAGxAIADUEUc40MrMwK2sausoqkfGIZs9UTx7RAcMcUagq0ZxmZs2J6dmoA9SgA) still shows error